# jhipster v7.9.0 got error when generate the project

Tags: jhipster

I was trying to create the project using the following .yo-rc.json file:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "baseName": "baby",
    "blueprints": [],
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "clientTheme": "none",
    "clientThemeVariant": "",
    "creationTimestamp": 1659322452305,
    "cypressAudit": false,
    "cypressCoverage": true,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "devServerPort": 4200,
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "enableGradleEnterprise": false,
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "jhipsterVersion": "7.9.0",
    "jwtSecretKey": "ZDkzZDZjZmFiYjljYTU4YzQ3MzI1ZDlmMTkxMTZkZjVlMzg3OWVlNDgwNzY3ZmQ5ZjcyNmUzYmFmOTc2ODcwMGZlZjRhZTgwZTQ4MDkyMGMxZDcyOGNmNTI3ZTU1YmRkZDA2M2MxNjEwODcyZWJhYzdhZWMyNjJlZGJhNzY3MDY=",
    "languages": ["en", "pt-br"],
    "messageBroker": false,
    "microfrontend": false,
    "microfrontends": [],
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "otherModules": [],
    "packageName": "com.mamazinha.baby",
    "pages": [],
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "reactive": false,
    "searchEngine": false,
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "serverSideOptions": [],
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "no",
    "skipCheckLengthOfIdentifier": false,
    "skipFakeData": false,
    "skipUserManagement": false,
    "testFrameworks": ["cypress"],
    "websocket": false,
    "withAdminUi": true
  }
}
```

I run the jhipster command on windows 10 at the powershell. I 've got the following error message:

```
PS C:\Users\Blog\Documents\Projects\_ERROR_v7.9.0_mamazinha-monolithic> npm run clean-www
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> baby@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT clean-www
> rimraf target/classes/static/app/{src,target/}
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Blog\Documents\Projects\_ERROR_v7.9.0_mamazinha-monolithic
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Blog\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-01T05_45_51_701Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Opened issue: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/19294

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The solution

It doesn't work if you run npm run clean-www command from windows powershell! After I run it using git bash on windows it all works out!

After that, I tried the hipster command at git bash and everything works fine!

Comment: This is strange, I did not find any reference to  ash in rimraf code and when I run `rimraf 'target/classes/static/app/{src,target/}'` in Powershell it works although I had to quote the dir regex due to {}

Comment: must the jhipster command run on git? I tried on command prompt also got the above  error, and I had to revert back to 7.8.1 which works fine. (Generating on Vue as frontend)

Comment: Hello @ZonG, it was an issue https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/19294 solved on jhipster version 7.9.2v https://www.jhipster.tech/2022/07/31/jhipster-release-7.9.2.html